# Is there a faster way to change the 0s in a linespace?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working with Jupyter Notebooks and I need to do some calculations using a `linspace` which go to `b` from `a`, the problem is that I get the Zero Division Error, so I was wondering if there was a faster way to change the 0s in a linespace, instead of going trough each element, check if it's a 0 and then change it with the smallest representable number?

Comment: Do you mean linspace?  As in `numpy.linspace`?

Comment: Do you mean "warning" instead of error? Numpy is happy for you to divide by 0, but warns you

Comment: @ChrisMueller Yes, sorry

Answer (score 2):

```
a= numpy.linspace(...)
zero_mask = a==0
```

is that what you mean?

Comment: I don't understand this, how can this replace the 0s that are in the linspace?

Comment: `a==0` identifies which elements are zero. Then you can change those with e.g. `a[a==0] = 0.1`